# My JavaScript works as inline code but not as an include file. Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form:

```
<form id="searchForm" class="search_field" method="get" action="">
...
...
</form>
```

Then this javascript:

```
    var form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
    form.doSearch1.onclick = searchPage;
    form.doSearch2.onclick = searchPage;
    form.showFeatureChoices.onclick = function( )
        {
            var cbs = form.featType;
            for ( var c = 0; c < cbs.length; ++c )
            {
                cbs[c].checked = false;
            }
            document.getElementById("featuresDiv").style.display = "block";
        }

function searchPage()
{
    var form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
    var searchText = form.searchBox.value.replace(/-/g,"");
    form.searchBox.value = searchText;

    if (searchText != "") 
    {
        // collect features to search for:
        var features = [ ];
        var featTypes = form.featType;
        for ( var f = 0; f < featTypes.length; ++f )
        {
            if ( featTypes[f].checked ) features.push( featTypes[f].value );
        }
        featureList = "'" + features.join("','") + "'";

        searchMsg("Searching for '" + searchText + "' ...");
        // startStatusUpdate(1000);
        // findTask.execute(findParams, showResults);
        var accord = dijit.byId("accordianContainer");
        var resultsPane = dijit.byId("resultsPane");
        accord.selectChild(resultsPane,true);

        doSearch( searchText, featureList );
    }
    else
    {
      searchMsg("No search criteria entered, enter search text");
    }   
}
```

If I embed this code in same file as the `<form...`, it works fine.

If however, I have this js in another file and use as include file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Views/JS/main.js"></script>
```

I get following error: "Object required" and it points to these lines:

```
form.doSearch1.onclick = searchPage;
form.doSearch2.onclick = searchPage;
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Just a bit more info, the js code shown above in a file called main.js which is in a folder called JS and Js is in a folder called Views. The

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include the JavaScript code in the same page, where is it in relation to the `form` element?  (Before or after it?)  How about when you reference the external JavaScript file?

I'm *guessing* that in the former case the code is at the end of the file, while in the latter case the `script` reference tag is at the beginning?

If that's true then what's happening is this code is being executed before the DOM is ready:

```
var form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
form.doSearch1.onclick = searchPage;
form.doSearch2.onclick = searchPage;
```

If the `form` tag hasn't been rendered to the DOM yet then that first line won't find anything, and the subsequent lines will fail as a result.  One approach is to put the `script` reference tags at the end, but that seems like a hack to me.  Sometimes there are good reasons to keep them in the page header, not the least of which is cleaner management of the code in many cases.  [There are other ways to hold off on executing JavaScript code until the DOM is ready.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: We should do both - Move script to bottom (as best practice, not as solution to this issue) and use document.ready

Comment: When the js is in the same page as form element, it is below the form element:

<form name="searchForm"...>
<script type="text/Javascript">
...
</script>

When referenced as externale file, it is between the head:

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Views/JS/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
then form element.

There are a bunch of those js file references.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh: That would indeed cause the error, then.  If the JavaScript is being evaluated before the `form` element has been added to the DOM then it won't be able to find that element.  It either needs to wait until the DOM is ready or it needs to occur after the `form` tag.

Comment: @David, thanks.

What would be the workaround then.

The boss doesn't want an inline js code.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh: Either include the `script` tag which references the external JavaScript file at the end of the HTML or wrap the code in a function which waits for the DOM to be loaded before executing.  (This is trivial to do with jQuery, the question to which I linked discusses how to do it without jQuery.)

Comment: @David, I included the file at end of html and it that problem is solved. It caused another problem but that is for a separate post. 

I will post that question separately.

Thanks for your help.